# Magento - importing images from a 3rd party XML file

Tags: magento

I am wondering how I'd upload images from a 3rd party XML feed to use as a products images?

I've seen the use of addImageToMediaGallery() but I am unsure what I'd need to do.

My assumptions are:

1) I will need to download all the images to a folder from my XML feed
2) Pass the image path into the addImageToMediaGallery method and set the image, small_image and thumbnails
3) call this method

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so my solution was to download the images using cURL and then save them to:

> media/import

Then I could use the following:

```
$product->addImageToMediaGallery(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import/' .  $filename, array('image', 'small_image','thumbnail'), false, false);
```

Where $filename is the filename of the image on the server.

Thanks to all who looked!

Answer (score 0):

best bet would be , download all images and convert xml file to be eatable with DataFlow and then just import the file with image paths like the default import behaves in Magento

Comment: But this XML file is updated daily. Plus I already have a custom PHP script that imports all the other product attributes and saves them.

Comment: what's stopping you taking the turn to standard approach ?