# How to connect images to magento when importing by xml file

Tags: image, magento, import

I have imported 100 products in Magento without an image via xml file. (I didn't have the pictures)
Now I also have images and want to import them to Magento, so in the XML file I have placed the images in the map /a/l/ and also on my server I have placed them in the map /a/l/.

(/a/l/ is also the map where the images are stored when adding them manually in magento. I have copied this line from some other products.)

When importing the xml file by running the profile in popup I get the message "Image does not exist"
So I can't get the image import working.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento - importing images from a 3rd party XML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041625/magento-importing-images-from-a-3rd-party-xml-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the images in `/media/import/` directory instead. Magento will find them there and move them to the appropriate place for you.

Comment: Thanks. What path do I have to define in my .xml file? Also /media/import/myfile.jpg ?

Comment: Image does not exist. showing this error. Can you please help me out during product upload in magento upload through csv

Comment: @vijay - If this question does not help you please start a new question and explain what is different from this one. That way more people can see you asking for help.

Comment: Actually, it needs to be /myfile.jpg (with a forward slash before the name).

Comment: @clockworkgeek: there is no import file in my media folder i place images at media/catalog/product/products folder and products folder is created by me but images are not uploading

Comment: @Suresh - Create the folder `/media/import/` if it does not exist. Then place the files inside that as described above. Putting them anywhere else will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Browse through your **csv** file to check your image path, and place it into **/media/import/**

Comment: there is no import file in media folder place images at  media/catalog/product/products but its not working